# cpio incorrectly unpacking initrd in Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: initramfs, cpio

I am trying to unpack initrd image:

```
# file /boot/initrd.img-4.11.0-14-generic
/boot/initrd.img-4.11.0-14-generic: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
# mkdir /tmp/initrd; cd /tmp/initrd
# cpio -i -d -H newc --no-absolute-filenames -F /boot/initrd.img-4.11.0-14-generic
194 blocks
# ls -R
.:
kernel

./kernel:
x86

./kernel/x86:
microcode

./kernel/x86/microcode:
GenuineIntel.bin
```

So cpio extracts only `./kernel` subdirectory of archive. But `lsinitramfs` show much more files inside it:

```
# lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-4.11.0-14-generic
/boot/initrd.img-4.11.0-14-generic
kernel
kernel/x86
kernel/x86/microcode
kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin
.
lib
lib/libnss_files.so.2
lib/cryptsetup

...

bin/egrep
init
run
```

How can I get all the archive contents?

Comment: Just googled the same problem and found an answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163353/251825

Comment: @Sergey Thanks! May be you can wtire this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have intel-microcode (you have) and/or amd64-micrcocode installed, the initrd consists of two concatenated images. The first image contains just the microcode. The second contains everything else. Your cpio command just extracts the first one.

The easiest way is to use `unmkinitramfs` from initramfs-tools >= 0.126, which is included in Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) and newer. On xenial you can just clone https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/initramfs-tools and call `unmkinitramfs` from this directory.